# logo image not overlapping menu div

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make my logo image overlap another div.

this logo has `position: relative` within a `wrapper`, and i want it to overlap another wrapper below it (the menu).

here's an image :

[image]
as you can see, the logo "Celebes Chocolate" is not overlapping the menu wrapper below it.

Comment: where is your image?..in your link there is no image..

Comment: show your code for header.